# Java not returning values when reading text file

Tags: java, arrays, object, text-files, readline

Java is returning string values when reading off a text file, but it will only return "0" for my integer values and "0.0" for my doubles.

```
  Cars car[] = new Cars[5];
  int cnt = 0;
  String line = inF.readLine();

  while(line != null){
     String[] field = line.split("\\s+");

     int yrData = Integer.parseInt(field[2]);
     double disData = Double.parseDouble(field[3]);

     car[cnt] = new Cars(field[0], field[1], yrData, disData);
     cnt++; 
     line = inF.readLine();
  }

  for(int i=0; i<cnt;  i++){
     System.out.println(i+1 +": "+ car[i]);
  }
```

Example:
What Java Returns--->
1: Name: Opel Model: Astra Year: 0 Disp: 0.0

What is in the text file:Opel Astra 1997 2.8

This is my constructor:

```
Cars(String dataForName, String dataForModel, int dataForYear, double dataForDisp){name = dataForName; model = dataForModel; int year = dataForYear; double disp = dataForDisp;}
```

This is my toString method:

```
public String toString(){String s = "Name: "+name+" Model: "+model+" Year: "+year+" Disp: "+disp; return s;}
```

The delimiter of the text is space(s).

Comment: Can you include the code for you constructor?  This should work.

Comment: And for the `toString` method as well.

Comment: What is the Delimiter of the text? is it space(s)   (or) TAB (\t) ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your constructor:

```
Cars(String dataForName, String dataForModel, int dataForYear, double dataForDisp){
    name = dataForName; 
    model = dataForModel; 
    int year = dataForYear; 
    double disp = dataForDisp;
}
```

you declare a new variable `year` and `disp` inside the constructor instead of setting the field in your class.  As a result, those values are never set so they use the default values of `0` and `0.0` respectively.

changing it to

```
 Cars(String dataForName, String dataForModel, int dataForYear, double dataForDisp){
    name = dataForName; 
    model = dataForModel; 
    year = dataForYear; 
    disp = dataForDisp;
 }
```

should work.